# How to click in a serie area chart below another serie area chart in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have this following chart: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/01ulJ.png

And how you can see, I have two area chart, a green one and a blue one.
The green one is bigger than the blue one so it's over blue one.

But I would like to display an alert for example, "Hello World", when the user click on the blue one series, but it keep impossible because the green one stay over and doesn't allow the click event fires.

Anyone know if is there any propertie that allows me click on the blue one series even being under the green area chart ?

Thank you Guys.

Comment: make an Secondary yAxis for  blue one

Comment: Thanks for the help @YounesZaidi but it's not usefull for me. I have a specific need to stay in the same yAxis.

Comment: And you don't want to simply change series orders ?

Comment: @Core972 Unfortunately no. I would like to make it no matter wich order the user choose, the marker always will be clickable even being under of another series.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this **live demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/6uq2gj8c/

In series' click I check whether the event happened below the line created by two points. I use *slope–intercept form* (`y = a*x + b`) for this. `trackByArea` must be enabled to fire the event properly.

```
  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      trackByArea: true,
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          var chart = this.chart;
          s1 = chart.series[0],
            p1 = s1.points[0],
            p2 = s1.points[1],
            x1 = p1.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
            y1 = p1.plotY + chart.plotTop,
            x2 = p2.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
            y2 = p2.plotY + chart.plotTop,
            eX = e.chartX, eY = e.chartY,
            // line equation: y = a*x + b
            a = (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2),
            b = y1 - a * x1,
            val = (a * eX + b);

          if (eX >= x1 && eX <= x2 && val < eY) {
            console.log('Clicked event over Series1!');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

To make this example fully functional these operations need to be performed for all line segments (it's easy to implement).

---

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.trackByArea